# Import won't import content in CCK image fields

Tags: entities, nodes, media, importing-exporting

I am using the [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) module to migrate thousands of nodes from a Drupal 5 site to a Drupal 6 site, and it is working really nicely except for one thing: It systematically fails to import my CCK image field and I get the following error message.

> Unknown error occurred attempting to import file: ***[path to file]***

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the images already in the directory in the new site?  For most import modules, the images *Have* to been in the directory before you start importing.

Comment: Thank you, I think that may indeed have been the problem.